# Trigger to update table column when new row is insert in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I want to write trigger to update table when new row is insert. I am using updatea Query like

```
UPDATE table SET
  geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a `BEFORE` trigger and then assign the new value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    new.geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(new.longitude, new.latitude), 4326);
    RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This can only be done in a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerinsert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON rdpr
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_update();
```

Answer (score 0):

I Solved by writing trigger function like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_update()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
   new.geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(new.longitude, new.latitude), 4326);

RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION function_update()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

and i wrote trigger to update

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerinsert
  Before INSERT
  ON rdpr
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE function_update();
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it. Use a before trigger and don't use `update`

Comment: It is **much** more efficient to do that in an BEFORE trigger and assign a value instead of running a (costly) update statement for each and every row that is inserted. There is no need to do that in an AFTER trigger

Comment: Before insert not working for me.and i want to know why we should not use use 'update' in function

Comment: Why is before "not working"? Did you try the example in my answer? And you shouldn't use `update` because it is a **lot** slower then simply changing the row that is inserted.

Comment: Thanks for help.I have to update other geom column when insert into rdpr lat,long

Comment: then assign them the same way.

Comment: lat,long is inserting into one table i.e rdpr table,then i want to update other table i.e rdprgeom table with geom.Now how i am updateing into same table.I Tried but not came

Comment: when i change my function to insert on other table getting error like 'column "longitude" does not exist'

Comment: I wrote update function like "insert into rdprgeo(geom) values(new.geom  = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(45, 45), 4326));"